# Segmentation fault with no detailed compiling warnings

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am trying to solve a puzzle and was going well for a while. I am used to get segmentation faults but I have overcame them till this one. Because in this one, I get no indicator that pointing where the segmentation fault may be occuring. I used both Dev C++ and MS Visual studio Community 2015 and they both give me nothing about the line which is the source of the error.

I am sharing the whole code below then I will share the specific function block which I give the most weight as the source of the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int boardSize, result=0;
int * board;

std::vector<std::vector<int> > tempVec;

void askSize()
{
    //
    std::cout << "type in the size of the boardSize: "<< std::endl;
    std::cin >> boardSize;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    board = new int [boardSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++)
    {
        //
        if( i < boardSize/2 )
        {
            //
            //std::cout<< i;
            board[i] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            board[i] = 0;
        }

    }
    for( int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++ )
    {
        //
        std::cout << *(board + i) <<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


void showBoard()
{
    //
    for( int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++ )
    {
        //
        std::cout << *(board + i) << ", " << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


int git(int * arrX, int x)
{
    //
    if( arrX[x+1] == 0 )
    {
        //
        arrX[x] = 0;
        arrX[x+1] = 1;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int checkGit(int * arrX, int x)
{
    //
    if( arrX[x+1] == 0 )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

void atla(int * arrX, int y, int jumpCount)
{
    //
    if( ( jumpCount > 0 && arrX[y+jumpCount*2+2] == 1 && y < boardSize-2 ) || ( jumpCount > 0 && arrX[y+jumpCount*2+1] == 0 && y < boardSize-2 ) )
    {
        //
        arrX[y] = 0;
        arrX[y + jumpCount*2] = 1;
        //return jumpCount;
    }
    else if( jumpCount > 0 && arrX[y+jumpCount*2+2] == 0 && y < boardSize-2 && arrX[y+jumpCount*2+1] == 1)
    {
        //
        atla(arrX, y, jumpCount+1);
    }
    else if( jumpCount == 0 && arrX[y+2] == 0 && arrX[y+1] == 1)
    {
        //
        atla(arrX, y, jumpCount+1);
    }
    else if( ( jumpCount == 0 && arrX[y+2] == 1 ) || ( jumpCount == 0 && arrX[y+1] == 0 ) )
    {
        //
        //return 0;
    }
}

int checkBoard(int * arrX)
{
    //
    for( int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++ )
    {
        //
        if( i < boardSize/2 )
        {
            //
            if( arrX[i] == 1 )
            {
                //
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //
            if( arrX[i] == 0 )
            {
                //
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int checkAtla( int * arrX, int x )
{
    //
    if( arrX[x + 1] == 1 && arrX[x + 2] == 0 )
    {
        //
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        //
        return 0;
    }
}

void changeTempArr(int x, int y, int * arrX)
{
    //
    if( y == 0 )
    {
        //
        git(arrX, x);
    }
    else if( y == 1 )
    {
        //
        atla(arrX, x, 0);
    }
}

void startBusiness( int counter, int * arrX )
{
    //
    /*
    int * tempArr = new int [boardSize];
    for( int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++ )
    {
        //
        tempArr[i] = arrX[i];
    }
    */
    for( int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++ )
    {
        //
        if( checkAtla(arrX, i) == 1 && i < boardSize - 2 )
        {
            //
            tempVec.push_back({i,1});
        }
        if( checkGit(arrX, i) == 1 && i < boardSize - 1 )
        {
            //
            tempVec.push_back({i,0});
        }

    }
    if( tempVec.size() > 0 )
    {
        //
        int ** possibilities = new int * [tempVec.size()];
        for( int i = 0; i < tempVec.size(); i++ )
        {
            //
            possibilities[i] = new int[2];
            possibilities[i][0] = tempVec[i][0];
            possibilities[i][1] = tempVec[i][1];
        }
        int possibilitySize = tempVec.size();
        tempVec.clear();
        //std::cout<< possibilities[10][0] << ", " << possibilities[10][1];
        for( int i = 0; i < possibilitySize; i++ )
        {
            //
            int * tempArr = new int [boardSize];
            for( int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++ )
            {
                //
                tempArr[i] = arrX[i];
                //std::cout << tempArr[i] << std::endl;
            }
            changeTempArr(possibilities[i][0], possibilities[i][1], tempArr);
            //std::cout << "check" << std::endl;
            startBusiness( counter + 1, tempArr );
        }

    }
    else
    {
        //
        if( checkBoard(arrX) == 1 )
        {
            //
            if( counter > result)
            {
                //
                result = counter;
                std::cout << result << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }


}

int main()
{
    askSize();
    startBusiness(0,board);
    std::cout << "the result is: " << result;
    return 0;
}
```

I think the problem is in between these lines(in the start business function):

```
int ** possibilities = new int * [tempVec.size()];
for( int i = 0; i < tempVec.size(); i++ )
{
    //
    possibilities[i] = new int[2];
    possibilities[i][0] = tempVec[i][0];
    possibilities[i][1] = tempVec[i][1];
}
int possibilitySize = tempVec.size();
tempVec.clear();
//std::cout<< possibilities[10][0] << ", " << possibilities[10][1];
for( int i = 0; i < possibilitySize; i++ )
{
    //
    int * tempArr = new int [boardSize];
    for( int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++ )
    {
        //
        tempArr[i] = arrX[i];
        //std::cout << tempArr[i] << std::endl;
    }
    changeTempArr(possibilities[i][0], possibilities[i][1], tempArr);
    //std::cout << "check" << std::endl;
    startBusiness( counter + 1, tempArr );
}
```

Because I can output the 'tempArr[i]' for local 'i' = 0 for the first time, and then things got messy. But really can not see which is the problematic line. Also another question, can it be the limited memory related problem?

Thanks.

Comment: generally - take advantage  of c++ safe containers. Use std::vector or std::aray instead of arrays . My guess is that you ran out of an array somewhere

Comment: did you run it under vs debugger (F5)? That will stop where the error happens

Comment: "Segmenttation faults" and "compiler warnings" are issues from two completely different unrelated universes. In general case, the compiler will not be able to help you to resolve segmentation faults. Don't expect any "compiler warnings" in such situations. "Compiler warnings" have absolutely nothing to do with it.

Comment: You leak memory like crazy, I would not be surprised if you get out of memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `startBusiness` function, you have

```
if( checkAtla(arrX, i) == 1 && i < boardSize - 2 )
{
    //
    tempVec.push_back({i,1});
}
```

That will call `checkAtla` first and then check the range. So you are calling `checkAtla` with `i==boardSize-2` and will cause a segfault.